# Error : shinyjs: extendShinyjs: `functions` argument must be provided

Tags: r, r-plotly, shinyjs

I'm very new to Shiny, so it might be a straightforward answer. The data visualization app is running correctly on my colleague's computer (who uses old packages versions). From what I gathered online, my issue seems to be linked to an update of the shiny library (maybe plotly too). I think I need to re-write these two extendShinyjs lines, but so far I was not able to find how.

```
o.ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
        useShinyjs(),
        extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('plotly_click-graphic', 'null'); }"),
        extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick_leg = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('traces', 'null'); }"),
        # l.tweaks,
```

Answer (score 4):

By changing the code as follow, it's now running !

```
jsCode <- "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('plotly_click-graphic', 'null'); }"
jsCode2 <- "shinyjs.resetClick_leg = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('traces', 'null'); }"

o.ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
        useShinyjs(),
        #extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('plotly_click-graphic', 'null'); }"),
        extendShinyjs(text = jsCode , functions = c("resetClick")),
        extendShinyjs(text = jsCode2 , functions = c("resetClick_leg")),
        #extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick_leg = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('traces', 'null'); }"),
```